# How aggregate in mongoDB by _id consists of two element(in Java)?

Tags: java, mongodb

MongoDB looks like:

```
{  "_id" : ObjectId("503d5024ff9038cdbfcc9da4"),
   "employee" : 61,
   "department" : "Sales",
   "amount" : 77,
   "type" : "airfare"
}
```

In mongoDB console I can aggregate by two params (`departments` and `type`):

`db.workers.aggregate(]{$group:{_id:{department:"$department",type:"$type"},amount_sum:{$sum:"$amount"}}}])`

How do it in java?

Comment: i am not aware of mongodb semantics but if you can tell what you want to achieve in java, i can tell you the solution

Comment: I would like to aggregate by: `department` and `type`,to calculate `$sum` of `amount`.

Comment: have a look here: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-aggregation-framework-with-java-driver/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this working in the shell, the question is how to turn this into Java.

```
db.workers.aggregate([{$group:{_id:{department:"$department",type:"$type"},
                               amount_sum:{$sum:"$amount"}}}])
```

This is very similar to [the example in Java tutorial for MongoDB.](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-aggregation-framework-with-java-driver/)

The only difference is that they use a simple DBObject for `_id` part of `$group` and you need to make a document to use as your `_id`.  Replace the line:

```
DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject( "_id", "$department");
```

with:

```
DBObject docFields = new BasicDBObject("department", "$department");
docFields.put("type", "$type");
DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject( "_id", docFields);
```

and you should be all set.